# How to create array of Panes in JavaFX(or how to control multiple similar panes)

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, pane

I have a Pane that includes label1, label2, label3 and a icon(pane with image). I duplicated that Pane and now i have 10 Pane 5 at left 5 at right and i named every item different for Pane(like left1label1,left2label1,right2label3)but i don't want to use different method for every single Pane.

I tried to create an array of panes but couldn't figure it out. All i want is easy way to manage this Panes. How should i do it?

```
public void leftPane1Config()
{

    leftPane1Label1.setText("Object");

    leftPane1Label2.setText("HP:"+ hp);
    leftPane1Label3.setText("EXP:"+ exp);

    Image img= new Image("directory");
    leftPane1Icon.setEffect(new ImageInput(img));
}

public void leftPane2Config()
{

    leftPane2Label1.setText("Object");

    leftPane2Label2.setText("HP:"+ hp);
    leftPane2Label3.setText("EXP:"+ exp);

    Image img= new Image("directory");
    leftPane2Icon.setEffect(new ImageInput(img));
}

.
.And 8 other 
.
```

I have tried to use something like this (trying to create an hierarchy but i couldn't make it :') ) but i couldn't use setText() so it didn't work.

```
leftPane1.getChildren().add(leftPane1Label1);
leftPane1.getChildren().get(0).setText??
```

Then i tried to use something like this

```
Pane[] leftPane= new Pane[5];
leftPane[0]= new Pane();
```

and again i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear what you're asking. Typically you would just write a method to create the panes and parameterize the parts the vary, in the usual way you do in any kind of programming.

```
public Pane createPane(String text1, String text2, String text3, URL image) {
    Image img = new Image(image.toExternalForm());
    // whatever layout you need here
    VBox pane = new VBox(
        new Label(text1),
        new Label(text2),
        new Label(text3),
        new ImageView(img)
    );
    // any other stuff you need to do
    return pane ;
}
```

And then of course you just call `createPane()` with the values you need and add the result to your scene graph however you need.

Comment: You can create custom objects with `new` as an alternative, like custom controls or widgets. Still, these kinds of parameterized factory methods are pretty common in JavaFX UI programming and compromise the most basic way and, in many cases, a perfectly reasonable way of customizing UI.